# How to read a checkbox's value in a excel file by django?

Tags: django, excel, checkbox

I have a excel file like this, there are some checkbox in the excel file .

[image]

I am using the django and the [Python Excel(xlrd/xlwt/xlutils)](http://www.python-excel.org/)

Questio One, I want to read the checkbox's value ,How to do ??

Questio Two, How to update the checkbox's value ??

Answer (score 5):

You can't read or modify the checkboxes using Python Excel (xlrd,xlwt,xltutils).

You can either use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) if you are on Windows platform or use [pyxll](https://www.pyxll.com).

See possible example for reading checkbox values below, to set a checkbox value just change 
the statement in the for loop to `cb.Value  = 1` or `cb.Value = 0`.

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'U:\Example.xls')
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
cb_dict = {}
for cb in ws.CheckBoxes():
    cb_dict[cb.Name] = cb.Value
excel.Application.Quit()
```

For pyxll examples see [here](https://www.pyxll.com/docs/macros.html) and [here](https://github.com/pyxll/pyxll-examples/).

Comment: Just a note that line 3 should use excel instead of xl